# Why is a subfolder created when syncing a second Mac's Documents folder via iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, finder, data-synchronization

I got a MacBook first and synced Documents and Desktop to iCloud. Then I got a Mac Mini and also enabled syncing. Now with the Desktop it works as expected: Same files on both Desktops. But in Documents a subfolder for my "Mac Mini Documents" was created. I was expecting a single shared Documents folder. Can I put those files (Mac Mini's Documents) in the main Documents folder without breaking anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works. You can now merge and clean up the documents as you wish. Start with a couple files, test and then move them all.

I do also keep backups from my mini for if or when a sync delete deletes more than I expected. You only have a limited time to recover them from the web app interface for iCloud

[image: icloud web app settings interface to recover deleted files]

https://www.icloud.com/settings/